# Is there any way to inform every on screen UITableViewCell when viewWillDisappear?

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I have a `UITableViewController` and a `MyTableViewCell` subclassing `UITableViewCell`.

I want to inform all the on-screen `MyTableViewCell`'s to do something related to their properties. How can I approach this?

Or, is there any way to get all the "instances" of on screen cells?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-[UITableView visibleCells]` returns an array of visible cells. Just iterate over the array in `viewWillDisappear:`.